# Or operation between two and operations

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Is there an optimal way to write a query for an OR operation between two AND operations in neo4j.

```
match(x)-[r]->(y) where y.name="a" with n match(n)--(y) where y.name="b"` OR 
match(x)-[r]->(y) where y.name="c" with n match(n)--(y) where y.name="d"`
```

I got an Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError !

Comment: When "with n" is executed, the "n" variable is not yet defined. Which variable are you actually trying to specify?

Answer (score 0):

Are you searching something similar to this :

MATCH (x)-[r]->(y) 
WHERE 
  (y.name="a" AND y.name="b") OR
  (y.name="c" AND y.name="d") 
RETURN x,r,y

You just have to use parentheses in your where query.

Comment: this is just an example, the query you gave is doing the same thing ... but to have a `y.mane` that is equal to `a` and `b`, obviously it will return nothing. But to perform what you are searching it's just a question of boolean algebra. So if you want a percise query, tell me what you are searching

Comment: Say 2 nodes named syntax and  Skill . Skill contains many relations with other nodes like say java, c, mysql, oracle, etc. I need all the syntax nodes that satisy the following constraint ( java AND mysql ) OR (c OR oracle) . I also tried a sloution for this where u apply descptive property which results in (java or mysql) and (java or oracle) and (c and mysql) and ( c or oracle). Is there any other alternative?